# How to run a GUI software from terminal, in a non-GUI supported Linux distro?

Tags: xorg, x11-forwarding, sqldeveloper

I have installed `CentOS 8` with no GUI support in a virtual machine.

Now I have `sqldeveloper` and `java jdk` properly installed on the same virtual machine. Env variables for java have already been set as well. I intend to use this VM to connect to another one with `Oracle 19c` installed.

The problem is that I simply can not run `sqldeveloper` from terminal, not even with `xhost +`, neither setting `DISPLAY` variable.

I have tried:

```
[root@machinename] export DISPLAY='localhost:0'

[root@machinename] xhost +
```

But then, I have returned

```
xhost: unable to open display "localhost:0"
```

If I try to run `./sqldeveloper` anyway, after setting `DISPLAY` as above, I got returned:

[image]

If I try to unset `DISPLAY`, based on the info returned (i.e. `DISPLAY` variable improperly set) and run `./sqldeveloper`, everything freezes at:

[image]

What is wrong? Is there any other value presumed for `DISPLAY` variable? Am I ignoring any other procedure?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: If you have no X server running, why are you expecting `DISPLAY=localhost:0` to work? Are you perhaps trying to use X11 forwarding over SSH? You don’t mention anything about SSH in your question.

Comment: Assume I am a complete newbie, please. I have just installed sqldeveloper in my virtual machine, this virtual machine has CentOS 8 with no GUI support as OS and I want to properly run sqldeveloper. What do I have to do?

Comment: Is it even possible? Or in a non-GUI supported environment, what I could do is to access my server remotely and- supose this server has GUI available and sqldeveloper installed- I would do X11 forwarding from this server to my local machine with no GUI? Is this correct? Then I would set Display variable and run the xhost command?

Comment: What exactly is your goal? Apart from running SQL Developer, that much is clear. Why not just install CentOS with GUI?

Comment: I am using sqldeveloper just as an example. My goal is to properly set a X11 Forwarding environment. Thus, installing CentOS with GUI would only drive me away from my goal. Thank you for your time.